# Django: KeyError when upload ICO file

Tags: python, django, django-models

My model is:

```
class Logo(models.Model):
    TYPES=(('logo', _('Logo')),('fav', _('Favicon')))

    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPES, default='logo')

    mimeType = models.CharField(
        max_length=127,
        verbose_name=_('Mime Type'),
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    src = ProcessedImageField(
        upload_to='logos/',
        options={'quality': 60},
        verbose_name=_('Source')
    )

    faviconLength = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=_('Favicon length'), blank=True, null=True)
    favicon = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Favicon'), blank=True, null=True)

    group = models.ForeignKey(
    Group,
    related_name='logo_group',
    verbose_name=_('Group'),
    null=False,
    blank=False
    )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.src.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Logo')
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name
```

When i try to upload ICO file, i have following exception:

KeyError at /admin/tenant/logo/add/
'ICO'

My question is: What is the problem with ICO files?

Comment: Post the full traceback. And are you saying that this problem only happens with ICO files, and other types are OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the answer. In PIL documentation i see that ICO is read-only, but i try to do write operation. This is the problem. After 2 hours debug and googlering :D i'm that problem is in the encoding. When i change my field to FileField, there is no problem anymore.